# Open all .csv in a folder and return a new output

Tags: r, csv, directory

I have a folder with a number of .csv (e.g. File1.csv, File2.csv etc.). I use the code you can see below to load the .csv files and do some transformations.

```
path <- "~/files/"
files <- list.files(path=path, pattern="*.csv$")
library("robustX", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library")
for(file in files)
{
  perpos <- which(strsplit(file, "")[[1]]==".")
  assign(
    gsub(" ","",substr(file, 1, perpos-1)), 
    data <-read.csv(paste(path,file,sep=""), sep=";"))
    Cb1 <- mvBACON(data[2:7],collect = 4, alpha=0.85, init.sel = c("Mahalanobis"))
    data$distance<-Cb1$dis
    data<-data[-c(13:31)]
    write.csv(data, "~/files/output/FILENAME.csv")
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to remove each dataframe at the end of the loop? So that my code does not keep all files in memory?
2. How can I write the new .csv file, with each one having the same name as the file loaded? For example, replace **FILENAME**.csv with File1.csv, File2.csv etc.

**EDIT**
Regarding the 1st question I am referring to removing file1, file2 etc., not data.
[image]

Comment: @etienne you should make that an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question : removing each dataframe at the end of the loop, you can add `rm(data)` just before the closing `}`. It will remove the `data` from the Global Environment.

For your second question use `paste0()` (that is, `paste` with `sep=''`) : `write.csv(data, paste0("~/files/output/",file))`

The last lines of your code should be :

```
for (file in files){
    # ...
    data<-data[-c(13:31)]
    write.csv(data, paste0("~/files/output/",file))
    rm(Cb1)
    rm(data)
}
```

Comment: ? really `for (file in file){ ... }`

Comment: yes, better. But syntax and semantic are correct: `file <- c("a", "b", "c"); for (file in file) print(file)` , i.e. could work as supposed if the vector `file` has the right values in the beginning.

Comment: @etienne Regarding the 1st question I am referring to removing file1, file2 etc., not data. (see the edit in starting post)

Comment: @manosbar:try `rm(list=gsub(" ","",substr(file, 1, perpos-1)))`